# Performing onClick() action and href in <a> tag in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to count how many times an user clicked in my custom button. The button is based on `<a href="/some_route"> Click me! </a>`. The whole code is:

```js
class CustomButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <a href={this.props.href} className="custom-button" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.text}
      </a>
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }
  
  buttonClicked = () => {
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <CustomButton text="Click me!" href="#" onClick={this.buttonClicked} />
        <p>
          Click counter: {this.state.counter}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <div><App /></div>, 
  document.getElementById('react')
)
```

```css
.custom-button {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #3f3b38;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.custom-button:hover {
  background-color: #FCFBFB;
  color: #3f3b38;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px #00000035;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

As you can see, if I pass `href="#"`, `onClick()` action is performed. **But** when I pass something else, i.e. `href="never-give-up"`, then I just go to the other page and no action is performed...

#### QUESTION

---

My question is 'why this happens' and how can I perform `onClick()` action **and** change page as the `<a>` tag does.

I would like have my code as simple as possible and do not use `react-router` as well.

---

Thanks for all responses!

Comment: You could try `target="_blank"` to check if the counter is not incrementing.

Comment: The counter is not incrementing, but presenting this in a short code snippet was quite difficult. I have this problem in my react app, where I am trying to count clicks on all buttons on the page. Some of them are built on `<a>` tag, some on `<span>`. Only those with `<a>` couses problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem have not anything with react, its just that `href` override the `onclick` event. now you could still fix this problem easy.

Note: that you need to also react-router so you could still maintained the counter data, or at list save it somewhere in db or session. because after the redirect the page will refresh and all `sate` will be lost

Here is an example on how to do it.

```js
class CustomButton extends React.Component {

  // this will handle your click event, inside as you see that this will handle the click event and the href rediarect to new location. So you could set both Onclick and the href togather
  clickEvent() {
    if (this.props.onClick)
      this.props.onClick();
    if (this.props.href && this.props.href != "" && this.props.href != "#")
      window.location.href = this.props.href; // rediarect after the click event has been performed.

  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      a href = "#" className = "custom-button" onClick = {this.clickEvent}> {
        this.props.text
      } <
      /a>
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  }

  buttonClicked = () => {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    })
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "container" >
      <
      CustomButton text = "Click me!"
      href = "#"
      onClick = {
        this.buttonClicked
      }
      /> <
      p >
      Click counter: {
        this.state.counter
      } <
      /p> < /
      div >
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <
  div > < App / > < /div>, 
  document.getElementById('react')
)
```

Comment: I found the solution a few hours ago, basically similar to yours. Anyway, I tried this and it worked, so I mark this as the solution for my problem. Thanks!